Doubt about metric tensor definition in Weinberg's Gravitation and Cosmology
In Weinberg's Gravitation and Cosmology, by using the Equivalence Principle, the author defines the metric tensor as (equation 3.2.7)
$$
g_{\mu \nu} \equiv \frac{\partial\xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial\xi^\beta}{\partial x^\nu} \eta_{\alpha \beta},
$$
where $\xi^\alpha$ are the coordinates in a free-falling frame and $x^\mu$ are arbitrary coordinates. This confuses me. Shouldn't that be valid only at a single point, or else wouldn't this equation imply that every metric tensor is isometric to $\eta_{\mu \nu}$, as in
$$
g_{\mu \nu} V^{\mu} V^{\nu} =  \frac{\partial\xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} \frac{\partial\xi^\beta}{\partial x^\nu} \eta_{\alpha \beta} V^{\mu} V^{\nu} = \eta_{\alpha \beta} \left( \frac{\partial\xi^\alpha}{\partial x^\mu} V^\mu\right) \left(\frac{\partial\xi^\beta}{\partial x^\nu} V^\nu\right) = \eta_{\alpha \beta} V^\alpha{'} V^{\beta}{'}
$$
(at least in the region where the coordinate system is valid)? Am I missing something relevant?

Yes this is at a point

in general relativity the metric depends on the position. what you have derived is the metric on the tangent space at the point $x$, which is flat minkowski space.
